# How to set a Canon 550D to shoot 1 second after pressing the shoot button on the camera?

Tags: canon, canon-550d

I need to avoid any movement in the tripod, so I want my camera to shoot 1 second after I press the button. How can I set it to shoot 1 second after I press the button? The choices available by default are 2 and 10 sec. How can I set it to 1 second?

Comment: Why specifically 1 second? wouldn't a 2 second waiting time accomplish the same result?

Comment: This is a limitation of most low-end cameras. Plenty of high-end cameras support custom timers from 0 to 30s and can take 1-10 shots.

Answer (score 18):

**You cannot. Use the 2s timer** instead which solves another problem too.

The *first* shake occurs when you release the shutter which both 2s and 10s timers avoid. This is obviously the one you know about.

The *second* shake occurs from the mirror in the camera as it raises to take the shot. To avoid this, the mirror must be up when the timer *starts*. This is automatically done on the 2s or 3s timers on several DSLRs, including yours.

Comment: But sadly not if you are doing bracketing. The mirror is only up for the first shot. Wish it was all three...

Answer (score 3):

Easy!

Use the [Canon TC80N3 timer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009XVA3). You can do a lot more with that timer than a 1 second wait. You can do intervals, time lapse, etc. You can do bulb exposures longer than 30 seconds. I love mine!

Now, it has worked on many Canon DSLRs that I've seen, just don't know about the 550D. But google it some and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the MagicLantern alternative firmware : http://magiclantern.wikia.com/
It contains many usefull features.
If delay shot is not there, you can ask them to add it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid moving a tripod a [cable](http://shop.usa.canon.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_10051_10051_171329_-1)/[remote](http://shop.usa.canon.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_10051_10051_246251_-1) shutter release is probably the best option.

Comment: If it shoots after 1 sec I think I can get the same results and avoid spending money on that cable. What do you think?

Comment: it's not the same thing because you are pressing the camera so you could "micro move" it. But in any case 2 second should work for you, no?